# Can I set the access tier when I upload a blob? If yes, then how to do that?

Tags: azure, go, blob

I did not find any way to set the access tier of a blob when I upload it, I know I can set a blob's access tier after I uploaded it, but I just want to know if I can upload the blob and set it's access tier in only one step. And if there is any golang API to do that?

I googled it but I got nothing helpful till now.

Here is what I did now, I mean upload it and then set it's access tier.

```
// Here's how to upload a blob.
blobURL := containerURL.NewBlockBlobURL(fileName)
ctx := context.Background()
_, err = azblob.UploadBufferToBlockBlob(ctx, data, blobURL, azblob.UploadToBlockBlobOptions{})
handleErrors(err)

//set tier
_, err = blobURL.SetTier(ctx, azblob.AccessTierCool, azblob.LeaseAccessConditions{})
handleErrors(err)
```

But I want to upload a blob and set it's tier in one step, not two steps as I do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No. According to the offical REST API reference, the blob operation you want is that to do via two REST APIs [`Put Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) and [`Set Blob Tier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier). Actually, all SDK APIs for different languages are implemented by wrapping the related REST APIs.

Except for Page Blob, you can set the header `x-ms-access-tier` in your operation request to do your want, as below.

[image]

For Block Blob, the operations in two steps are necessary, and can not be merged.

Comment: Seems to be out of date. Since version 2018-11-09, block blobs do support setting the access tier via this header. [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible using the new x-ms-access-tier header:

[x-ms-access-tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier)

[REST API with auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhateverYourNameSpaceIs
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string StorageKey = @"PutYourStorageKeyHere";
        private const string StorageAccount = "PutYourStorageAccountHere";
        private const string ContainerName = "PutYourContainerNameHere";
        private const string Method = "PUT";
        private const string ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
        private static readonly string BlobStorageTier = StorageTier.Cool;
        private static readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> HttpContentHeaders = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("x-ms-access-tier", BlobStorageTier),
            new Tuple<string, string>("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R")),
            new Tuple<string, string>("x-ms-version", "2018-11-09"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("Content-Type", ContentType),
        };
        static async Task Main()
        {
            await UploadBlobToAzure("DestinationFileNameWithoutPath", "LocalFileNameWithPath");
        }
        static async Task<int> UploadBlobToAzure(string blobName, string fileName)
        {
            int returnValue = (int)AzureCopyStatus.Unknown;
            try
            {
                using var client = new HttpClient();
                using var content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
                HttpContentHeaders.ForEach(x => content.Headers.Add(x.Item1, x.Item2));
                var stringToSign = $"{Method}\n\n\n{content.Headers.ContentLength.Value}\n\n{ContentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
                foreach (var httpContentHeader in HttpContentHeaders.Where(x => x.Item1 != "Content-Type").OrderBy(x => x.Item1))
                    stringToSign += $"{httpContentHeader.Item1.ToLower()}:{httpContentHeader.Item2}\n";
                stringToSign += $"/{StorageAccount}/{ContainerName}/{blobName}";
                HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey));
                string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedKey", $"{StorageAccount}:{signature}");
                var httpResponse = await client.PutAsync($"https://{StorageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{ContainerName}/{blobName}", content);
                returnValue = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
            }
            catch (IOException ioException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ioException.ToString());
                returnValue = (int)AzureCopyStatus.FileNotFound;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                returnValue = (int)AzureCopyStatus.Error;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
        internal enum AzureCopyStatus
        {
            Unknown = -1,
            Error = 0,
            FileNotFound = 2
        }
        internal static class StorageTier
        {
            internal static string Cool = "Cool";
            internal static string Hot = "Hot";
        }
    }
}
```